# recordData don't load, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to load the record fields but for some reason it doesn't load, it's very simple and follow documentation exactly:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="String" />
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        targetRecord="{!v.record}"
        targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}" 
        targetError="{!v.error}"
        fields="Name, SBQQ__Account__c"
    />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Then the JS:

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Simple Record:", component.get("v.simpleRecord"));
    console.log("Record ID:", component.get("v.recordId"));
    
},
```

The output is:

```
Simple Record: null
Record ID: 0015w00002CsD6JAAV
```

I don't know why it get the record id but don't load the fields?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you getting in your v.error attribute?

Comment: It say Undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition between `doInit` and the loading process for `force:recordData.` force:recordData` [loads its data asynchronously](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation):

> force:recordData loads data asynchronously since it may retrieve data from the server. To track when the record is loaded or changed, use the recordUpdated event or place a change handler on targetRecords or targetFields.

and is not guaranteed to complete prior to the execution of the `init` handler.

If you need to react to data being loaded, implement a change handler in your Aura component.

Comment: Solved it by using this and getting the result via promise.